# LibGDX basic stage draw error

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to create a game, but my code keeps giving me error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no uniform with name 'u_projModelView' in shader
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.fetchUniformLocation(ShaderProgram.java:287)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.fetchUniformLocation(ShaderProgram.java:277)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.setUniformMatrix(ShaderProgram.java:507)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.setUniformMatrix(ShaderProgram.java:498)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ImmediateModeRenderer20.flush(ImmediateModeRenderer20.java:147)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ImmediateModeRenderer20.end(ImmediateModeRenderer20.java:160)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.end(ShapeRenderer.java:1104)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.check(ShapeRenderer.java:1092)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.rect(ShapeRenderer.java:389)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table.drawDebugRects(Table.java:1224)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table.drawDebug(Table.java:1204)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.drawDebugChildren(Group.java:156)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.drawDebug(Group.java:139)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.drawDebug(Stage.java:169)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.draw(Stage.java:132)
at net.lukshe.lukshegame2.screens.MainMenu.render(MainMenu.java:71)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at net.lukshe.lukshegame2.LuksheGame.render(LuksheGame.java:23)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:215)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

MainMenu.java:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL30;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton.TextButtonStyle;

public class MainMenu implements Screen {

private Stage stage; //done
private TextureAtlas atlas; //done
private Skin skin; //done
private Table table; //done
private TextButton buttonplay, buttonexit;
private BitmapFont white; //done
private Label heading;

@Override
public void show() {
    stage = new Stage();

    atlas = new TextureAtlas("ui/button.pack");
    skin = new Skin(atlas);
    table = new Table(skin);
    table.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    white = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font/white.fnt"), false);

    //Set the button style
    TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("buttonup");
    textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("buttondown");
    textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetX = 1;
    textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetY = -1;
    textButtonStyle.font = white;
    textButtonStyle.fontColor = Color.BLACK;

    //Creating exit button
    buttonexit = new TextButton("Exit", textButtonStyle);
    buttonexit.pad(20);

    //Add button to the table
    table.add(buttonexit);

    //Debug
    table.debug();

    //Add table to the stage
    stage.addActor(table);

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    //OpenGL settings
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //Render at the speed of delta
    stage.act(delta);

    //Draw stage
    stage.draw();

}
```

LuksheGame.java:

```
public class LuksheGame extends Game {

public static final String NAME = "Lukse game (LibGDX)", VERSION = "Pre-Alpha 0.0.0.2";

@Override
public void create() {
    setScreen(new Splash());
}

@Override
public void dispose() {     
    super.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render() {
    super.render();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {     
    super.resize(width, height);
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    super.pause();
}

@Override
public void resume() {      
    super.resume();
}
```

}

If someone can help me, please help.

EDIT: 
MainMenu.java is called from Splash.java. In Splash class I'm using Tween engine to increase and decrease opacity of the splash screen.
Splash.java:

```
public class Splash implements Screen {

private SpriteBatch batch;
private Sprite splash;
private TweenManager twm;


@Override
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    twm = new TweenManager();
    Tween.registerAccessor(Sprite.class, new SpriteAccessor());

    Texture splashtexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/splash.png"));
    splash = new Sprite(splashtexture);
    splash.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    Tween.set(splash, SpriteAccessor.alpha).target(0).start(twm);
    Tween.to(splash, SpriteAccessor.alpha, 2).target(1).repeatYoyo(1, 2).setCallback(new TweenCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(int type, BaseTween<?> source) {
            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new MainMenu());
        }
    }).start(twm);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    twm.update(delta);

    batch.begin();
    splash.draw(batch);
    batch.end();

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    splash.getTexture().dispose();
}
```

}

Comment: formatted stack trace

Comment: First, you don't need to override all the methods in your game class, if all you do is call the super method. Next I can't see any obvious errors in your code, are you doing somethin in your SplashScreen? Do you set a custom shader somewhere? Any other code that effects your stuff you posted here?

Comment: @PinkieSwirl I'm using Tween engine and main menu class is called out from the splash screen.

Comment: Can you upload a minimal version that reproduces the error? I don't use tween engine, but I looks ok. Just one thing, since you don't keep references to your Screens and you don't call dispose in your hide method, you never dispose the SplashScreen resources? Even Game.dispose only calls Screen.hide!

Comment: @PinkieSwirl I've been experimenting for a while and I tried adding buttons as an actor. It seems that Table class is just invalid argument for the Stage actor. EDIT: removed the table.debug() statement, everything works right now

Comment: The Table class is a valid actor, and debug draw should give no problems. so if that causes the problem it would be nice if you could report that error on the libgdx bug tracker (with a minimal working example and version, etc...)